# What's a good translation for 说法？

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

> 在我们这边是有这种**说法**——混血儿会比较聪明。

I know several meanings for it.

官方说法, Official statement;

讨说法, seek explanation or justice.

今日说法, talk about law.

However, here 说法 means a kind of public opinion. Can it be translated to `saying` which convey the 说 part meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, in this context, the translation of `saying` or `common saying` would work.

Besides the several meanings you pointed out, 说法 also has another meaning that is commonly seen: wording or the way that something is said. An example is:

> 你刚刚说得有点太复杂，换一种说法意思可能清楚些。
>
> The way you were explaining was a little too complicated, perhaps changing the wording might make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

说法 generally means **statement**.
讨说法 means **ask for a statement** (from other person or official etc).

今日说法 is a special case, the two characters 说法 are two different words but not one:

今日, **说**, **法** the literal meaning word by word are:
today, **talking**, **the law**.
The talking about the law today.

The character 法 pronounced the 3rd tone here while in the word 说法 it is neutral tone.